# Need help parsing blocks of text

Tags: c#, regex, file, parsing, block

I need help parsing this example text:

```
[item1]
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7
2550 coins 995 200000 7
2550 coins 995 200000 7   
[/item1]  
[item2]   
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7   
2550 coins 995 200000 7   
2550 coins 995 200000     
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
[/item2]    
[item3]    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
2550 coins 995 200000 7    
[/item3]
```

I have no idea how to read the data from each item while keeping the item heading(item1 etc..) associated with data. I am sorry but I have no idea how to approach this, so far this is what I have got for parsing one item without the headings.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Ashes", "d", "a", "g");
        //dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
        String fileName = "Drops.de";
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        int[] nums = new int[4];

        int npcID;
        int itemID;
        int itemAmount;
        int itemRarity;
        string itemName;

       // string currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
             string currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();


            if (!currentLine.Contains('#') && currentLine != "" && !currentLine.Contains("["))
            {     
                String[] s = currentLine.Split(' ');
                npcID = int.Parse(s[0]);
                itemName = (s[1]);
                itemID = int.Parse(s[2]);
                itemAmount = int.Parse(s[3]);
                itemRarity = int.Parse(s[4]);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(itemName, itemID, itemAmount, itemRarity);
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                streamReader.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        streamReader.Close();

    }
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what kind of output you are expecting?

Comment: I am currently outputting it as a row for each set of data from an item. So if it is possible maybe storing the data from each item into a table which can be displayed in a DataGridvView. I'm not even sure if it's possible though.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't required u are reading it second time something wrong here

```
else
{
     streamReader.ReadLine();
}
```

in the case of item2 ->> 4th record you may got exception index out bound array
at 
         itemRarity = int.Parse(s[4]);

cause there is no fifth element

the best you can do is at if condition

```
if(Regex.match(currentline,@"^\d+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s*?$"))
{
    #now do your logic here
}
```

Here is Complete Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fileName = "d:\\Drops.txt";
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); 
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Head","Head");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("npcID", "npcID");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("itemName", "itemName");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("itemID", "itemID");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("itemAmount", "itemAmount");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("itemRarity", "itemRarity");

        string itemhead = "Not Found";
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

            if (Regex.IsMatch(currentLine, @"^\d+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+?\s*?$"))
            {
                List<string> s = new List<string>();
                s.Add(itemhead);
                s.AddRange(currentLine.Split(' '));

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s.ToArray());
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            else if(Regex.IsMatch(currentLine,@"\[[^/]*\]"))
            {
                itemhead = Regex.Match(currentLine, @"\[([^/]*)\]").Groups[0].Value;
            }


        }

        streamReader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have a branch for reading lines with the [item] identifyer ... use it to read the desired info about the item ... store that info in a variable outside of your loop ... everytime you read a line without the [item] identifyer, you can still use that variable to know what item this line belongs to ...

```
    string headingItem="unknown Item";
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
         string currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

        if (!currentLine.Contains('#') && currentLine != "" && !currentLine.Contains("["))
        {     
            String[] s = currentLine.Split(' ');
            npcID = int.Parse(s[0]);
            itemName = (s[1]);
            itemID = int.Parse(s[2]);
            itemAmount = int.Parse(s[3]);
            itemRarity = int.Parse(s[4]);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(headingItem, itemName, itemID, itemAmount, itemRarity);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            headingItem=currentLine;
        }

    }
```